# Sequence alignment with one to many characters

Tags: algorithms, strings, edit-distance

I'm trying to align a sequence of characters together, I found that sequence alignment algorithms which use dynamic programming like Needleman-Wunsch or Smith–Waterman only align one character with one character beside allowing character substitution, deletion or insertion.

For example, if I have a set of similarly sounding characters, like

```
monir, monier, muneer, munir, mounir, mouneer
```

The alignment algorithm will produce the following output

```
m u n i - r
| | | |   |
m o n e e r
```

Is there a way to adapt these algorithms (or an alternative algorithm) to consider aligning/substituting character with more than one character in order to output something like

```
m u n i  r
| | | |  |
m o n ee r
```

Please note that, I'm using the standard java implementation for these algorithms and I don't have a predefined list of similarly sounding characters, so I'm trying to aligning the similar words together in order to extract these alignments.

Comment: Why don't you just merge gaps into neighbouring mismatches?

Comment: @Raphael the algorithm compare character by character to get the score of matching the characters and the gaps should not be always applicable to be matched with its neighbors

Comment: Why not? When will it be?

Comment: @Raphael consider these strings, how can you do that? The normal alignment will produce: 
(- a l s h o u a - i b i / e - l s h - - a e e b y) but actually, I need it to be aligned like (a l  sh  ou a   i  b   i / e  l  sh   -   a ee b  y)

Comment: You will have to make up your mind. In the question you say that the alignments are supposed to *yield* (candidates for) similar-sounding (groups of) characters. Now you talk of how things "need" to be.

Comment: More to the point, note that you can fiddle around with the cost matrix for mismatches for alignments; the same basic algorithm still works. For instance, you can make (mis)matching `e` to `t` more expensive than `e` to `a`. I daresay that a high cost for matching vowels to consonants may already improve your result. You can certainly "encode" more knowledge about pronounciation that you already have in this fashion (e.g. `t` and `d` may concur but never `t` and `n`). Even things like "a gap next to a good match is cheap, but not one next to a bad match", but that becomes more intricate.

Comment: Please clarify your assumptions and the desired kind of result in the question. This may be more about modelling domain knowledge than algorithms, and so far you don't provide much to go on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a variant of the Smith-Waterman algorithm. It assigns a penalty for an insertion or deletion, and also assigns a penalty for a substition, that depends on the two letters. (This is used for calculating the similarity of protein sequences, e.g. with a lower penalty for replacing an acidic residue with another acidic one.)

For your case, the penalty score needs to depend on the previous context, so you will have to adapt a standard implementation.

Answer (score -2):

If I understood your problem correctly, a trie data structure may help you. The main challenge would be after the first mismatch, match the upcomming characters. I'm not sure how I would hack it, but it may not be that hard.

Hope it helps. Regards

Comment: Welcome to [cs.se]! Thanks for contributing but this is far too vague for an answer. You're basically saying, "Tries might work but they might not. And maybe they're really hard to use for this. I dunno, really." That would be OK for a comment but it's not an answer.

Comment: Since you cannot comment yet, one possibility is to flesh out what you said, provided it is correct.